# Facebook SharePhoto dialog does't show in swift 4

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-share

**FBSDKSharingDelegate**

```
let FBImage = FBSDKSharePhoto()

FBImage.image = snap
FBImage.isUserGenerated = true

let content = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
content.photos = [FBImage]
let dialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
dialog.mode = .automatic
dialog.delegate = self
dialog.fromViewController = self
dialog.shareContent = content

if dialog.canShow(){
   dialog.show()
 }
```

// Facebook Auth Permission

```
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"id,name,first_name,email,birthday"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in })
```

> -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Install Facebook Application in your Mobile.**

[image]

> I have Not error But Application not install in my mobile so don't open dialog box.